# I can't delete file type "File"

Tags: file, operating-system

Basically, my code failed to download this image from the internet, and it created this kind of ghost file that the file type is just called File, and it has 0 bytes of data. But it just lingers in my file and I can't delete it under any circumstances. I have tried deleted in cmd as well but it says it doesn't exist even though it shows up in my dir. I can't find anything online.

[image: Ghost File with 0 bytes. What sense does this make?]

Comment: on which OS? on linux try `sudo rm -rf <file/dir>`

Comment: I am on Windows.

Comment: show us what commands have you tried.